# How to understand the PKI's revocation of keys and certificates function?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

> A public key infrastructure is a collection of hardware, software, people, policies, and procedures that implement the generation, management, storage, distribution, and revocation of keys and certificates based on public key cryptography.

How can PKI can realize the revocation of keys and certificates function?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to know, but it is essentially people who report certificates which need to be revoked, software and hardware which makes revocation possible (CRL, OCSP...), processes which require to check for revocation etc.

Comment: I can understand the PKI's generation, storage, and distribution of keys and certificates. but I don't know the revocation of PKI, if wen want to remove it, we can just `rm -rf` it. why this has relationship with PKI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... but I don't know the revocation of PKI, if wen want to remove it, **we can just rm -rf it**. why this has relationship with PKI?

If a certificate is compromised no one should trust this certificate anymore, even though it was signed by a trusted CA and is not expired. It is **not enough that the CA simply takes the certificate away from the owner** since a compromise means that somebody else different from the owner might be in possession of the certificate and the associated private key and might misuse it.

Instead the CA need to inform everybody that this specific certificate should no longer be trusted, even though it was issued by the CA and is not yet expired. And this is what certificate revocation is: whenever someone gets a message signed with a specific certificate (like in case of TLS) he should check with the CA if the certificate is revoked or not. This can be done by checking against  a certificate revocation list (CRL)  provided by the CA or by directly asking the CA (or some designated party) using OCSP if a specific certificate is revoked or maybe other methods.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I still have a doubt about whether PKI have a function of keys' revocation.

Comment: @244boy: I unable to understand where this doubt comes from and thus I'm not able to help you further. If you would explain your doubt in much more detail than currently I could maybe help.

Comment: When a key is compromised, the key owner tells the CA. The CA adds the certificate to a Certificate Revocation List, and has the CA sign the list. The CA then publishes the CRL (makes the list available.) When validating a cert, you retrieve the CRL from the CA (the CRL‘s URL can be found in a field on the certificate) and ensure the cert isn’t on the list.